# PHPMailer cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: php, eclipse

Caros desenvolvedores,
Na IDE do Eclipse aparece o seguinte aviso:

**PHPMailer cannot be resolved to a type**

Instalei o PHPMailer através do *composer*, o estranho é que o código está funcionando corretamente, ou seja, o e-mail é enviado com sucesso, porém por toda a IDE fica esses avisos chatos. Alguém sabe como consertar isso?
Segue a parte do código onde aparece o aviso.

```
    require $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/vendor/autoload.php";
    ...
    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(); //O aviso aparece aqui
    ...
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta acessar o menu Project/Clean, depois clicando com o botão direito no teu servidor e faz um clean nele (Vai limpar e fazer o rebuild)